# Switch textField classes

Tags: swift, enums, textfield, collectionview

**I have CollectionView with CollectionViewCells that I switched. First I have this**

[image: I need to set PhoneNumber]

**After I get my secondCell with code**

[image: here is my secondCell]

**I use same sell with different methods to change text, but in first cell.textField as custom cocoapod library TKFormTextField and in second case I want to use simple UITextField. What enum and how should I use it?**

**here is my cell**

```
    class PhoneNumberCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell, NiBLoadable {



    @IBOutlet weak var phoneLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var PhoneNumberTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var SecurityLabel: UILabel!


    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        Decorator.decorate(self)

    }

    func setPhoneLabelText(text: String) {
        phoneLabel.text = text
    }

    func setSecurityLabel(text: String) {
        SecurityLabel.text = text
    }


}

    extension PhoneNumberCollectionViewCell {

        fileprivate class Decorator {
            static func decorate(_ cell: PhoneNumberCollectionViewCell) {
                cell.phoneLabel.textColor = UIColor(red: 50.0/255.0, green: 50.0/255.0, blue: 50.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
                cell.SecurityLabel.textColor = UIColor(red: 50.0/255.0, green: 50.0/255.0, blue: 50.0/255.0, alpha: 0.6)
                cell.phoneLabel.font = UIFont(name: "OpenSans", size: 15)
                cell.SecurityLabel.font = UIFont(name: "OpenSans", size: 12)
            }
        }
    }




    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let models = model[indexPath.row]

    switch models {
    case .phoneNumber:
        if let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: PhoneNumberCollectionViewCell.name, for: indexPath) as? PhoneNumberCollectionViewCell {
            cell.PhoneNumberTextField.text = self.phoneNumber
            cell.setSecurityLabel(text: "_ALLYOURDATAISINSECUREDAREA")
            cell.setPhoneLabelText(text: "_YOURPHONENUMBER")
            return cell
        }
    case .confirmCode:
        if let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: PhoneNumberCollectionViewCell.name, for: indexPath) as? PhoneNumberCollectionViewCell {
            cell.PhoneNumberTextField.text = self.confirmCode
            cell.setPhoneLabelText(text: "_ENTERCODEFROMSMS")
            cell.setSecurityLabel(text: "_IFYOUDIDNTRECIEVETHESMS")
            cell.PhoneNumberTextField.defaultTextAttributes.updateValue(5.0, forKey: NSAttributedString.Key(rawValue: NSAttributedString.Key.kern.rawValue))
            return cell
        }
    }
    return UICollectionViewCell.init()
}
```

Comment: add your function `cellForItemAt` function

Comment: I added bellow. look plz

Answer (score 0):

You have more option to do this:

- Create two different custom cell for the different options.

  ```
  func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
  let models = model[indexPath.row]

  switch models {
  case .phoneNumber:
      if let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: FirstCustomCell.name, for: indexPath) as? FirstCustomCell {
          cell.PhoneNumberTextField.text = self.phoneNumber
          cell.setSecurityLabel(text: "_ALLYOURDATAISINSECUREDAREA")
          cell.setPhoneLabelText(text: "_YOURPHONENUMBER")
          return cell
      }
  case .confirmCode:
      if let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: SecondCustomCell.name, for: indexPath) as? SecondCustomCell {
          cell.PhoneNumberTextField.text = self.confirmCode
          cell.setPhoneLabelText(text: "_ENTERCODEFROMSMS")
          cell.setSecurityLabel(text: "_IFYOUDIDNTRECIEVETHESMS")
          cell.PhoneNumberTextField.defaultTextAttributes.updateValue(5.0, forKey: NSAttributedString.Key(rawValue: NSAttributedString.Key.kern.rawValue))
          return cell
      }
  }
  return UICollectionViewCell.init()
  }
  ```
- On the PhoneNumberCollectionViewCell create both of the textfields and set alphas to 0.

  ```
  class PhoneNumberCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell, NiBLoadable {

  @IBOutlet weak var phoneLabel: UILabel!
  @IBOutlet weak var PhoneNumberTextField: TKFormTextField!,
  @IBOutlet weak var CodeFromSmsTextField: UITextField!
  @IBOutlet weak var SecurityLabel: UILabel!

  override func awakeFromNib() {
      super.awakeFromNib()
      Decorator.decorate(self)
      PhoneNumberTextField.alpha = 0
      CodeFromSmsTextField.alpha = 0

  }

  func setPhoneLabelText(text: String) {
      phoneLabel.text = text
  }

  func setSecurityLabel(text: String) {
      SecurityLabel.text = text
  }
  }
  ```

And after this, you can show what you need.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let models = model[indexPath.row]

    guard let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: PhoneNumberCollectionViewCell.name, for: indexPath) as? PhoneNumberCollectionViewCell else { return UICollectionViewCell() }

    switch models {
    case .phoneNumber:
            cell.PhoneNumberTextField.text = self.phoneNumber
            cell.setSecurityLabel(text: "_ALLYOURDATAISINSECUREDAREA")
            cell.setPhoneLabelText(text: "_YOURPHONENUMBER")
            cell.PhoneNumberTextField.alpha = 1
    case .confirmCode:
            cell.PhoneNumberTextField.text = self.confirmCode
            cell.setPhoneLabelText(text: "_ENTERCODEFROMSMS")
            cell.setSecurityLabel(text: "_IFYOUDIDNTRECIEVETHESMS")
            cell.PhoneNumberTextField.defaultTextAttributes.updateValue(5.0, forKey: NSAttributedString.Key(rawValue: NSAttributedString.Key.kern.rawValue))
            cell.CodeFromSmsTextField.alpha = 1
    }
}
```